# selectBooleanCheckbox with ajax is not working on TomEE 8.0.8

Tags: ajax, primefaces, tomee-8

I have a question concerning JSF/PrimeFaces on TomEE. Running the following code (PrimeFaces 7.0)

```
                <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{dashboardUIController.includeMyself}">
                    <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{dashboardUIController.onIncludeMyself()}" update="teamVisitedCountriesChart teamTravelsForProjectsChart"/>
                </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

on TomEE version 8.0.6, everything is fine. Running it on TomEE version 8.0.8, it results in the following exception:

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.myfaces.shared.renderkit.html.util.ResourceUtils.renderDefaultJsfJsInlineIfNecessary(ResourceUtils.java:183)
        at org.apache.myfaces.shared.renderkit.html.HtmlCheckboxRendererBase.encodeEnd(HtmlCheckboxRendererBase.java:68)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:675)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeAll(UIComponentBase.java:555)
        at org.apache.myfaces.shared.renderkit.RendererUtils.renderChildren(RendererUtils.java:688)
        at org.apache.myfaces.shared.renderkit.html.HtmlGroupRendererBase.encodeEnd(HtmlGroupRendererBase.java:150)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:675)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeAll(UIComponentBase.java:555)
        at org.apache.myfaces.shared.renderkit.html.HtmlGridRendererBase.renderChildren(HtmlGridRendererBase.java:376)
        at org.apache.myfaces.shared.renderkit.html.HtmlGridRendererBase.encodeEnd(HtmlGridRendererBase.java:189)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:675)
        at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:87)
        at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:69)
        at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:85)
        at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:69)
        at org.primefaces.component.layout.LayoutUnitRenderer.encodeEnd(LayoutUnitRenderer.java:60)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:675)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeAll(UIComponentBase.java:555)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeAll(UIComponentBase.java:551)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeAll(UIComponentBase.java:551)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeAll(UIComponentBase.java:551)
        at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.renderView(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:1897)
        at org.apache.myfaces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:315)
        at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:73)
        at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:73)
        at org.omnifaces.viewhandler.OmniViewHandler.renderView(OmniViewHandler.java:121)
        at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:122)
        at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:266)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.apache.openejb.server.httpd.EEFilter.doFilter(EEFilter.java:67)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:45)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:667)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBSecurityListener$RequestCapturer.invoke(OpenEJBSecurityListener.java:97)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1726)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

It seems that TomEE 8.0.8 includes a Mojarra version, which forbids an ajax inside a selectBooleanCheckBox element.
So, does anybody know the exact root cause of this exception, and also, how to get it running on TomEE 8.0.8?

Thanks!

Comment: are you sure you use the Mojarra version? The stacktrace inclues MyFaces classes and the exception will be fixed for 8.0.9: https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/tomee-dev/202111.mbox/browser

Comment: Can you try with 8.0.9?